# Generate map with polygon aggregation in Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapes

Generate the map of federal units from the municipalities map in PostgreSQL with Postgis.

Example below:

[image]

The table has only the geometry information and the id.

I tried:

```sql
SELECT st_union(m.geom)
FROM uf, municipios as m
WHERE ST_Intersects(uf.geom, m.geom)
AND st_contains(uf.geom, m.geom)
GROUP BY uf.gid
```

But he returns geometries that do not belong to the state.

Note: The operation has the purpose of studies!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to group the municipios by federal unit ID:

```
select 
 <<some_id_for_federal_unit>>>
,st_union(geom) as geom
from municipios
group by 1
```

and you don't need to join it with "uf" table (don't understand why you need these intersects/contains conditions)